# AngularJS component Layout engine fxLayoutAlign="stretch" not working

Tags: javascript, angular, flexbox, angular-material

Using [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) and [angular/material2](https://github.com/angular/material2), the `fxLayoutAlign="stretch"` directive appears to be broken. However, `fxLayoutAlign="start"` and `fxLayoutAlign="end"` directives work as intended. Please check this [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/utAvGqkgKInTNPxb7GTO?p=preview).

`fxLayoutAlign="stretch"` is [documented](http://cssreference.io/flexbox/#align-content) as:

> Each line will stretch to fill the remaining space.

Is this a problem with:

1. Flex Layout engine?
2. Angular component Layout engine?
3. My code?

Comment: What is the use of "stretch"? Can't find it in the docu https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview

Comment: Thx! This looks to me like it does what it made for. Your boxes are in different rows. The documentation says: `it only applies if flex-wrap: wrap is present, and if there are multiple lines of flexbox items.` and this is what your plnkr does not provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking is just flex layout 'center'. 'stretch' works with container of multiple rows.

> it only applies if `flex-wrap: wrap` is present, and if there are multiple lines of flexbox items

```
  <md-card>
      <md-card-subtitle>fxLayoutAlign="center"</md-card-subtitle>
      <md-card-content>
          <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutAlign="center">
              <md-slide-toggle>One</md-slide-toggle>
              <md-slide-toggle>Two</md-slide-toggle>
          </div>
      </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
```